# Java Android, Countdown Timer and ProgressBar (read first)

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I have count down timer which is display by ProgressBar and successfully. But unfortunately there is problems.

1. The progressBar Start in 1/5 instead 0/5. and Stuck 2 seconds in 4/5 progress
2. If I recall the Function of Count down Timer before

   ```
   public void onFinish() {
      progresBar.setProgress(100);
   }
   ```

display will be mess up for a while.

I really miss Unity Engine with `Time.deltaTime`;

Here is my code:

```
countDownTimer2 = new CountDownTimer(5000,1000) {
    int i = 0;

    @Override
    public void onTick(long milliSecondUntilFinished) {
        i++;
        progresBar.setProgress((int) i * 100 / (5000/1000));
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        progresBar.setProgress(100);
    }
}.start();
```

Comment: "If I recall the Function of Count down Timer" - Can you show code where you are calling ? Are you using same object for calling ?
Thanks :-)

Comment: btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (input.getText().toString().equals(questionNumber)) {
                    rightAnswer();
                } else {
                    wrongAnswer();
                }
                getRandomQuestion();
            }


        });

Comment: Countdown Timer inside getRandomQuestion();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are incrementing your `i` variable before setting your progress. When onTick() is called for the first time, the value of `i` is `1`. Thus progress you are setting is `20` which is equivalent to `1/5`. Use this -

```
@Override
public void onTick(long milliSecondUntilFinished) {
    progresBar.setProgress((int) i * 100 / (5000/1000));
    i++;
}
```

Also, you should better use `milliSecondUntilFinished` to find progress instead of unneccesarily introducing `i` variable.

For the problem with the display, I highly doubt that you have not canceled the timer already running before calling a new one. If yes, then both timer would be running until older one finishes (till this point, the progress bar will be behaving weirdly).

You can cancel the previous timer as -

```
countDownTimer2.cancel();
```

Do this before starting a new one.

Comment: Just help start with 0/5, but not solved the mess up and 2 seconds for 4/5.

Comment: @Jon please look at the edit. Also, post more code for your other problem i.e. stuck at 4/5 for two seconds.

Comment: What the code to cancel the previous Countdown Timer.... to prevent both timer running along

Answer (score 0):

Using:

```
countDownTimer2 = new CountDownTimer(1000,5000) {
    int i = 0;
    @Override
    public void onTick(long milliSecondUntilFinished) {
        i++;
        progresBar.setProgress((int) i * 100 / (5000/1000));
    }
    @Override
    public void onFinish() {

        progresBar.setProgress(100);

    }
}.start();
```

Comment: get error for putting new CountDownTimer(**1000,5000**)